# Why does main have an int in front of it and why could my Professor be excluding it?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

So in my professor's slides he simply gives examples like:

```
main()
{...
}
```

Right? But when I put this in visual studio it gives an error and it works when I put int in front of main. 
**Why would my professor not put int in front of main?**
Can main be any other type of variable?
Also I see a lot of int main(void). Why is this necessary? Can anything else be put in as a parameter?

Comment: Your professor is wrong.  (or is simplifying the code to fit on a slide)

Comment: Because your professor is writing code as if it were 1988.  Even then it was a poor idea.  As to your issue, you're using a C++ compiler, not C.  VS only supports C89, VC++ rejects that code as C++ does not support implicit int.

Comment: Your professor is incompetent; you should report him or her.

Comment: This is a valid declaration in C, not C++.

Comment: I realized he reuses slides that he made in 2004 without updating them. So that answers that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`main` returns `int`. In older versions of C you could leave out the `int` and the compiler would pretend that you had said `int`. In C++, if 'main' doesn't explicitly return a value, it magically returns 0. You can return three values from `main`: 0, EXIT_SUCCESS, and EXIT_FAILURE. 0 is equivalent to EXIT_SUCCESS. The two named values are defined in `<stdlib.h>` and if you're coding in C++ in `<cstdlib>`.

The `void` is a C-style declaration that a function takes no arguments. In C++ you don't need it; a function that has no arguments in its declaration takes no arguments.

In general, though, `main` takes two arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Those are the command-line arguments. `argc` is the number of arguments, and `argv` is an array of pointers to C-style strings that hold the arguments. The first string (`argv[0]`) is the name of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using either: C++ or C99 or C11.

C89 had an implicit `int` rule that mades `main()` equivalent to `int main()`. This does not exist in C++ and no longer exists since C99.

As you mentioned you are using Visual Studio and it does not support C99 and C11, you are probably compiling your program with the C++ compiler and not the C compiler.

Comment: He's using VC++ (VC is C89) +1

Answer (score 1):

The standard form of the `main` function, traditionally, is

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

The `int` in the front means the `main` function returns an `int`, which is the exit code of `main`. The perimeter passed in by the operating system `argc` and `argv` are related to command-line arguments. `argc` is an `int` indicating the number of arguments passed in to the program, including the name of the program. And `argv` is pointed to the individual arguments. You can use `argv[index]` to access them. There are several handy libraries for parsing arguments, such as getopt.